# No puedo enviar e-mail

Tags: c#

No puedo enviar e-mail desde este código en consola C# desde un hotmail. Me muestra error.

Quiero saber el motivo.

Antes, funcionaba tal como está el año pasado, por noviembre, llega Enero del 2023 y no funciona.

¿Qué ha ocurrido exactamente?

Puedes escribir, como dije antes, modo consola, tu correo electrónico, luego la contraseña, seguido del e-mail a quien lo quieras enviar incluso a ti mismo para hacer pruebas, el asunto y el mensaje.

Te cuenta cuantos caracteres has escrito de tu mensaje, al rato dice enviado o no, pero no dice el motivo, solo pone error.

Código C#:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;

namespace Enviar_email_Consola_08
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            // Variables.
            string usuario, contraseña, destinatario, asunto, mensaje;
            const int MAXIMA_LONGITUD = 40000;

            #region Configuración ventana.
            // Título de la ventana y versión del .Net usando.
            Console.Title = "Gestor correo electrónico Hotmail. "
                + typeof(string).Assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion;

            // Tamaño de la ventana, x, y, o ancho y alto.
            const byte ANCHO_X = 70, ALTO_Y = 25;
            Console.SetWindowSize(ANCHO_X, ALTO_Y);

            // Color de fondo.
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;

            // Color de las letras.
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;

            // Limpiar pantalla y dejarlo todo en color de fondo.
            Console.Clear();

            // Visible el cursor.
            Console.CursorVisible = true;
            #endregion

            // Título del programa.
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t----------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\tEnviar Correo Electrónico");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t----------------------------------------");

            try
            {

                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.Write("\t\tTu correo electrónico: ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                usuario = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.Write("\t\tIntroducir contraseña: ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                contraseña = LeerPassword();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.Write("\t\tDestinatario: ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                destinatario = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.Write("\t\tAsunto: ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                asunto = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.Write("\t\tMensaje: ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                //mensaje = Console.ReadLine();

                #region Enviar más de 255 caracteres.
                // #########################################################################
                Stream entradaDeDatos = Console.OpenStandardInput();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[MAXIMA_LONGITUD];
                int numerosBytesLeidos = entradaDeDatos.Read(buffer, 0, MAXIMA_LONGITUD);
                char[] chars = Console.InputEncoding.GetChars(buffer, 0, numerosBytesLeidos);
                mensaje = new string(chars);
                // #########################################################################
                #endregion

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
                Console.Write("\t\tCantidad de texto introducido: ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                Console.WriteLine(mensaje.Length);

                MailMessage correo = new MailMessage(usuario, destinatario, asunto, mensaje)
                {
                    // Enviar textos con tildes.
                    BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
                };

                SmtpClient servidor = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com")
                {
                    Port = 587 // 25 ó 465.
                };
                NetworkCredential credenciales = new NetworkCredential(usuario, contraseña);
                servidor.Credentials = credenciales;
                servidor.EnableSsl = true;

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.WriteLine("\t\tEnviando correo...");
                servidor.Send(correo);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("\t\t¡Correo enviado satisfactoriamente!");
                correo.Dispose();
                Console.CursorVisible = false;
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: \n");
                Console.WriteLine("\t\t" + ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.WriteLine("\t\tNo se ha enviado el correo.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }

        #region Asterisco para contraseñas.
        // A la hora de introducir la contraseña, se sustituye por asterístos (*) en pantalla.
        public static string LeerPassword()
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int contador = 0;

            do
            {
                cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {

                    sb.Append(cki.KeyChar);
                    if (contador < 1)
                    {
                        Console.Write("*");
                    }
                    contador++;
                }

                else
                {
                    break;
                }

            } while (true);
            Console.WriteLine();
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Espero tener una respuesta, que me da más que cuestión de hacer nuevos códigos, es más bien de configuración de servidores o algo de eso.

Saludos.

Comment: Buenas ¿que error te da? probablemente sea que se te haya subido la seguridad de la cuenta automáticamente que usas para enviar como lo hace gmail de vez en cuando

Comment: También he encontrado una [página](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/email/common-3rd-party-smtp-settings/) actualizada del 10 de enero que utiliza una configuración diferente a la que utilizas.

Comment: "Me muestra error." Cuál es ese error?

Comment: Estoy seguro de que alguien preguntó lo mismo.

Comment: Si hasta el año pasado funcionaba, entonces no creo que sea tu código, quizás cambio el port , pusieron algunas restriccion3s o simplemente el usuario o contraseña no existe o usuario bloqueado y así sucesivamente pero como no pones el detalle del error difícil se evaluar que podría estar causándole.

Comment: El error no lo da los e-mail ni el compilador. Sale algo de credenciales y me da que es seguridad de Gmail,  también  Hotmail. Cuando llegue a mi casa, subo las capturas.

Comment: Hola de nuevo.

Aquí intentando enviar un mensaje desde hotmail.

Ver imagen.

https://i.postimg.cc/kX3sbVSm/Captura.jpg

Saludos.

Comment: Han cambiado en el hotmail el de antes que fue este, smtp.live.com, por este otro nuevo, smtp.office365.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Han cambiado en el hotmail el de antes que fue este, smtp.live.com, por este otro nuevo, smtp.office365.com.